# Open .mongo file extension?

Tags: mongodb

I've downloaded a .mongo file (`<filename>.mongo`) as part of a data package and am trying to figure out how to open it. I've tried connecting via the pymongo driver, but no dice... it's not behaving like a database. After searching, I can't find anything about this particular extension. Seems like it should be simple, but I just can't figure it out!

Comment: Might be a dump or export file. Try `mongorestore` or `mongoimport`. Can you open it in notepad++ or similar? If it's not a binary file, post the first few lines.

Comment: Did you try open it in a simple text editor? Maybe it's a dump of JSON objects?

Comment: Thanks all! Turns out it handles like a JSON file (you were right that it was a dump of JSON objects) and I was overthinking it.